# Ember: How do I remove dynamic segements from my route if their values are null?

Tags: ember.js

I have a search route with many parameters. At the moment my URL contains all of the parameters set to default values if they aren't set by the user. I want to be able to remove, add the parameters to URL depending on whether the user has selected them. For instance. If the user has selected both min and max prices and sizes it would be;

```
minprice/0/maxprice/5000000/minsize/0/maxsize/10000/
```

But if they have only selected price it would be;

```
minprice/0/maxprice/5000000
```

I have tried to use the serialize method in my search route, but that seems only to pass the dynamic segments to the router which I have defined, with the rest coming up undefined.

So how can I dynamically add/remove dynamic segments to my route?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you  use ember's `queryParams` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a computed property on my search object. On the property I check for changes in other search properties, I then return a property called 'FullUrl' and use that in my route as a dynamic segement. This gives me complete control over the url.

On a page refresh I simply parse my computed property in order to get my search object properties and maintain state.